# Is there efficient way to load data to cache with ignite python thin client?

Tags: ignite, thin-client

using put() and put_all() is very inefficient to load large amount of data. And there is no interface in python thin client ( pyignite ) to use data streamer.
Is there better way?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Sticking with the Python thin client `putAll` is about the best you can manage.

If you want to stick with Python, you might be able to use PySpark and its Ignite integration.

Alternatively, you'd have to use one of the platforms with a supported thick client.